# How to access php from html?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am sorry if this is a repeating question, but I can't find anyone who might have the same question as me yet. I am new in html and php, and I am trying to learn more by practising, basically creating a registration form and keep all the data in the MySQL database, by using xampp. I have created a registration form and saved it as a .html file format, but how can I use php to send the user input from html to the MySQL database? I have seen a lot of examples on Google, but most of them are using php file format, for example instead of registration.html, they use registration.php. I really do appreciate your help. Thank you very much StackOverflow community members.

P/S: I use Visual Studio Code to do this

Comment: Point your form's `action` attribute to the `.php` script. (https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php -- here's a good starting point

Comment: This question is really a bit too broad for SO's Q/A format - you really need a basic PHP/MySQL (or MariaDB) tutorial. *Aside* "phpMyAdmin" is a web-based tool used to manage MySQL/MariaDB databases, it's not a database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: write this code in your html file

in form action redirect it to the php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="st.php">
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Step 2 create st.php file and call the action

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])){
        //your code
       header('Location:yourHTMLFile.html?status=success');//redirect to your html with status
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example to insert some data in to the MySQL database using PHP
1. Create a Index.php page in a new folder(“764”) created under public_html folder present in your home directory

To use a PHP script on your web page, you just need to end the file name with .php and make sure the permissions on the file are set correctly. Any files to be accessed by the web server must be publically readable, but none of your PHP files (nor the directory containing them) may be group or publically writable. Following are the commands you can use for setting the permissions in linux:

chmod 755 public_html
chmod 644 public_html/764/index.php

The PHP page will have two simple text boxes for the user to enter some data in to it. Label them to be Firstname and Lastname.

INDEX.PHP

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>A small example page to insert some data in to the MySQL database using PHP</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

We also need to make sure that the form method attribute is “post” so as to access the data being entered in a reliable way in the next page being directed “insert.php” so that the data being entered in the textboxes can then be saved to the database in the “insert.php” page.

2. To connect to MySQL :-
   Before you can access your MySQL database, you must contact the system administrators to request an account.

Once the administrators have notified you that your account has been created, you may connect using the following instructions.

Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin and type your MySQL ID and password being given.

3. Now enter the new table name “nametable” , number of fields in that table as “2” and hit GO button.
4. Enter the field names to be “firstname” and “lastname” and keep the length attributes to be “20” for both the fields. The default type of VARCHAR is kept as it is.
5. After the table fields are being created, the following screen will be shown to you.
6. Now we need to make a connection to the MySQL database and then send this entered data from our textboxes. For that we create a new PHP page “insert.php” and use the following connection strings to the connection variable $con

After making a connection, a SQL query is being written to enter this data in to the MySQL database being created (“nametable”)

To tell the user that the data is being entered we set the echo to "1 record added"

INSERT.PHP

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cis_id","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
  }
mysql_select_db("cis_id", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO nametable (fname, lname)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

7. Now type the index page URL in your browser and enter some data in to the textboxes. Submit the Query.
8. For browsing the data, you need to click on Database: cis_id on top of the page (http://localhost/phpmyadmin)  to get to the database tables page. Then click on the browse button as shown below, beside the “nametable” which you have already created to browse through the entered data.
9. the data being entered in to the MySQL database table being created.

Here is the reference.

http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~hankley/d764/tut06/GopisettyPHP.html

Note: Please write questions in proper way and internet is everything to get whatever you want. Hope you will search first and when you are helpless, post question with piece of code. Then only we can help in this forum.

Comment: `mysql_connect`? That function has been defunct for years - and you've got a serious SQL injection vulnerability there... *"Any files to be accessed by the web server must be publically readable"* ... not strictly true, they need to be group readable - e.g. `640` for files if owned by `:www-data` (for example).