# I am new to php langauge and i dunno how to connect html and php page it would be really helpful for me

Tags: php, html, mysql, syntax, backend

I have made a product landing page (in html ) and a register web page (in php)
I want the user to click on register icon on the html page such that the user should go on to  the register page (made in php), to enter it's credentials.
what should i do to solve this problem

Comment: May be this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066620/how-to-access-php-from-html

Answer (score 0):

welcome!

Let's say the register page is named `register.php`.

Then simply create a link around the register icon on your landing page, or use text, and link to the `register.php` file.

E. g.:

```
<a href="register.php"> Register</a>
```

Or if it's on another server, use the full URL (the address the register form in PHP is reachable from your browser):

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/register.php"> Register</a>
```

Navigating from a .html to a .php-file and vice versa can simply be done using normal HTML links (`<a>` tag).

Comment: i tried this but the php file gets downloaded instead of opening